# FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error)

Tags: firebase, flutter, recaptcha, firebase-app-check

I try to use Firebase Appcheck and Emulator together during development process. I thought that Appcheck can work when deployment completed but it doesn't work after deployment too. However,debug console return below error when It try to upload a file to the storage.

`FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error).`

1. Appcheck for Firebase Storage : Enforced from Firebase Console - Appcheck
2. Storage.rules is as follows:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

3. Related initialization code `at the top of index.html body` as follows:

```
   <script>self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
  initializeAppCheck(app , {
    provider: ReCaptchaV3Provider("My Recaptha V3 Site Key"),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
  });
  </script>
```

4. AppCheck activating code in `main.dart` as follows:

```
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'My Recaptha V3 Site Key',
    );
```

5. I activate AuthEmulator and StorageEmulator when debug mode activated.

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
await FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator('localhost', 9199);
```

How to get rid of the error ?

Comment: Did you add AppCheck debug token to Firebase console?

Comment: Yes. I have added the token to Firebase given by emulator console.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same problem

Comment: I haven't found any solution by now.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit too late for this post. for anyone else having this problem:
I Had the same error in flutter .. The issue was related to the [Updating the Debug Tokens for local testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider?hl=en&authuser=0#web).. Once you generate the token, I'd recommend saving it as a string in your HTML file. Instead of the flag set to true.